# Can't insert element into nested stl set of ints

Tags: c++, stl, set, iterator

I have a nested set of ints but I cannot insert elements into the nested sets.

```
std::set<std::set<int> > centre_as_set = bitset_to_set(centre->second->bit_partitions);
std::set<std::set<int> >::iterator set_itr;
for ( set_itr = centre_as_set.begin(); set_itr != centre_as_set.end(); ++set_itr ) {
    set_itr->insert(4);
    std::set<int>::iterator node_itr;
    for ( node_itr = set_itr->begin(); node_itr != set_itr->end(); ++node_itr ) {
            std::cout << *node_itr;
        }
    }
}
```

The error is

> Partition_standalone.cpp:612: error:
>   passing ‘const std::set, std::allocator >’
>   as ‘this’ argument of
>   ‘std::pair, _Compare,
>   typename
>   _Alloc::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator,
>   bool> std::set<_Key, _Compare,
>   _Alloc>::insert(const _Key&) [with _Key = int, _Compare =  std::less, _Alloc =
>   std::allocator]’ discards
>   qualifiers

I can't quite decipher that template error, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The elements in a set are not mutable and you are trying to use the non-const member function `insert()` on a `const` instance of `std::set<int>`. There is the following nice comment if you follow the `iterator` symbol to its declaration in `stl_set.h`:

```
// _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
// DR 103. set::iterator is required to be modifiable,
// but this allows modification of keys.
typedef typename _Rep_type::const_iterator iterator;
```

C++98 and C++03 allowed modification, but this is a defect and already fixed in non-ancient GCC versions and VC10. The mentioned defect report can be found [here](http://std.dkuug.dk/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#103) and will be incorporated into the next standard.

Use e.g. something like the following instead to add the value `4`:

```
// Readability:
typedef std::set<int> IntSet;
typedef std::set<IntSet> IntSetSet;

// Helper:
IntSetSet add_value_to_sets(const IntSetSet& in, int i) {
    IntSetSet ss;
    IntSetSet::iterator set_itr;
    for ( set_itr = in.begin(); set_itr != in.end(); ++set_itr ) {
        IntSet s = *set_itr;
        s.insert(4);
        ss.insert(s);
    }
    return ss;
}

// ...
IntSetSet centre_as_set = 
    add_value_to_sets(bitset_to_set(centre->second->bit_partitions), 4);
```

Comment: Ow. I dont know if i like this glibcxx feature. This effectively prevents changing the set contents even if the change wouldnt have an effect on the ordering. E.g. changing attributes which are not compared.

Comment: I'd say most of the use-cases where this is useful are better covered by associative containers like `std::map`. For me its definitely better than accidentally breaking everything at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This answer is wrong as per the comment of georg.

I dont have a compiler here, but the full declaration of std::set is:

```
template < class Key, class Compare = less<Key>,
           class Allocator = allocator<Key> > class set;
```

The "Key" of the outermost set is "std::set". The Comparator is "std::less>", or short "operator<(set, set)" which is undefined. The compiler warns about this only on the first use/instantiation of the comparator.

I dont think there is a useful ordering/comparator for std::set's. You are better off using std::vector which doesnt order the elements and doesnt need a comparator.

Oh, and it is not allowed to change (at runtime) the set keys if this would affect the ordering. But that would be a runtime error, not a compile error.

Comment: There is an `operator<`, see e.g. [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/operators/).

Comment: It's not a runtime error, it's a compile error and that is what his problem is.